# how to calculate a sequence of numbers followed by sequence of operators

Tags: python, c, pointers

[Description of what the function is required to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKKlS.png)

```
{
    int res = strtol(arguments[2], NULL, 10);
    int number_of_elements = strtol(arguments[1], NULL, 10);
    for(int i = 2; i <= number_of_elements; i++)
    {
        if(*arguments[number_of_elements + i] == '+')
        {
            res += *arguments[i + 1];
        }
        else if(*arguments[number_of_elements + i] == '-')
        {
            res -= *arguments[i + 1];
        }
        else if(*arguments[number_of_elements + i] == '*')
        {
            res *= *arguments[i + 1];
        }
        else if(*arguments[number_of_elements + i] == '/')
        {
            res /= *arguments[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

That was my solution in C for the problem which is not working although I tested the same logic in python and it was working fine.
Here is my solution in python:

```
    command = args[0]
    number_of_elements = args[1]
    res = args[2]
    for i in range(2, number_of_elements + 1):
        if args[number_of_elements + i] == '+':
            res += args[i + 1]
            print(f"{res} {args[number_of_elements + i]} {args[i + 1]} = {res + args[i+1]}")
        elif args[number_of_elements + i] == '-':
            res -= args[i + 1]
            print(f"{res} {args[number_of_elements + i]} {args[i + 1]} = {res - args[i+1]}")
        elif args[number_of_elements + i] == '*':
            res *= args[i + 1]
            print(f"{res} {args[number_of_elements + i]} {args[i + 1]} = {res - args[i+1]}")
        elif args[number_of_elements + i] == '/':
            res //= args[i + 1]
            print(f"{res} {args[number_of_elements + i]} {args[i + 1]} = {res - args[i+1]}")
    print(res)
```

So, since this is the first time for dealing with C what is wrong with my code I don't seem to get it why to returns wrong values although it's running without any errors.

Comment: please post the problem description in your question as text

Comment: In C, strings and single characters are not freely interchangeable. If the array of arguments is string, string, then the next is also string.

Comment: You have UB (undefined behavior). `arguments` has a count of `number_of_arguments`. So, when `i` is 2, you are already accessing beyond the end of the `arguments` array when you do: `arguments[number_of_arguments + i]`

Comment: @WeatherVane that is what I was missing thanks !!